Programmatically sign VBA code in MS Access
We have a quite big software with a few MS Access projects (accdb, mda, mdb) with lots of forms and code in it.
We have a tool that takes an Access file (accdb, mda, mdb) and disassembles it into text files (each form, report, module, class, ... is one file). And we have another tool, that creates a new Access file and puts all the text files as objects back into the Access file. Everything works fine.
Now we want to secure our code with a signature certificate (re-invented feature of MS Access). For that you need a suitable certificate, then you open the VBA editor of your access file and choose the certificate to use under Tools | Digital signature...
Every time you change code in this Access file, it gets signed automatically (when the certificate is present on the computer).
But here's the problem. I changed our tool to put together an Access file from the text files to not create a new Access file. Instead it takes an empty Access file (that I provide) that is already signed and imports the objects into this. So far, so good...
But I assume that Access signs either all the code or at least the new code every time a new object is imported, and that takes time. So, the time needed to assemble an Access file blew up from 55 seconds to 27 minutes.
So, my question is, is there any way to choose the certificate for the signature in code? Either in VBA code or in external code like .NET (using Access.Interop)?
That way I could assemble an unsigned file the old way, and only sign it after it is assembled completely.

Actually, you don't really need to sign the file, and if you add a trusted folder to the registry, then the application will run without any nags or prompts.
So, we currently use Inno for our installer. And we of course always deploy a compiled accDE.
So, in inno, we simply add the folder where we install the application, and set that folder as trusted, and once done, then the application runs without any nags or prompts, or even needing any kind of being signed.
Hence, this registry setting:
This example is for 2010:
So, we set (turn off) VBA warnings, and then set the install folder as trusted. This quite much does the same thing when you manually do this from the Access UI.
; Access 2010

Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "VBAWarnings"; ValueData: "1"                                                ; Check: HasAccess2010()
Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\ControlMIS"; ValueType: String; ValueName: "(Default)"; ValueData: ""                     ; Check: HasAccess2010()
Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\ControlMIS"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "AllowSubfolders"; ValueData: "1"               ; Check: HasAccess2010()
Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\ControlMIS"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Date"; ValueData: "12/17/2012 1:31 PM"        ; Check: HasAccess2010()
Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\ControlMIS"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Description"; ValueData: "12/17/2012 1:31 PM" ; Check: HasAccess2010()
Root: HKCU      ; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\ControlMIS"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "c:\ControlMIS\"            ; Check: HasAccess2010()

Seems to me, setting the above is a whole lot less efforts then trying to self sign the application. And introduction of some security certificate has just as many issues as it supposed to solve.
Due to the above, then I never had to go down the road of signing Access applications anyway, so consider the above.

Thank you, but using trusted folders is not secure enough for us (we did exactly that as long as Access didn't have the opportunity to sign the code). Every malicious Access file, that you save into one of your trusted folders will run.

That's 100% fair. Keep in mind anyone with full version in most cases can accept the warning prompt and thus they are running as trusted.  And we always use a custom folder,  hence user's would have to know to place a access file in that folder,  and hence I can't say you gain much security here since user's can answer yes to allow running of such applications.  Of course we always deploy a compiled accde, and we always provide a desktop shortcut and we always run with /runtime.  So, not much security advantages here, but I'll accept your wanting a signed app.
